# how to Group my list items for more readability

Tags: javascript

my list result display I need to create spaces or group them  between my displayed list result I tried using the break   tags but they don't work

```
function GetProductDetails(barcodeId, coords)
{
    $.getJSON("api/products/?barcodeId=" + barcodeId + "&latitude=" + coords.latitude + "&longitude=" + coords.longitude)
        .done(function (data)
        {
            $('#result').append(data.message)
            console.log(data)
            var list = $("#result").append('<ul></ul>').find('ul');
            $.each(data.results, function (i, item)
            {
                if(data.results == null)
                {

                    $('#result').append(data.message)
                }

                else
                {
                    list.append('<li>ShopName :' + item.retailerName + '</li>');
                    list.append('<li>Name : ' + item.productName + '</li>');
                    list.append('<li>Rand :' + item.price + '</li>');
                    list.append('<li>Distance in Km :' + item.Distance + '</li>');

                }

            });

            $("#result").append(ul);

        });
}
```

Comment: There is a preview... please check it before posting! :3

Comment: What do you mean, you "tried using tags"? What's the question? Are you asking how to apply a CSS style to the last list element so there's extra padding on the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

```
list.append('<li><b>ShopName</b><p>' + item.retailerName + '</p></li>');
list.append('<li><b>Name</b><p>' + item.productName + '</p></li>');
list.append('<li><b>Rand</b><p>' + item.price + '</p></li>');
list.append('<li><b>Distance</b><p>' + item.Distance + '</p></li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that `list` is always going to be the first `ul` in your results box, no matter how many you actually add. Also, your final `$("#result").append(ul)` is an error because there is no `ul` variable.

Try this:

```
var list = document.getElementById('result').appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
data.results.forEach(function(item) {
    list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
              .appendChild(document.createTextNode("ShopName : "+item.retailerName));
    list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
              .appendChild(document.createTextNode("Name : "+item.productName));
    list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
              .appendChild(document.createTextNode("Rand : "+item.price));
    list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
              .appendChild(document.createTextNode("Distance in Km : "+item.Distance));
});
```

[Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) may be more verbose to write, but it is immensely easier to understand and use, once you get past that mental block ;) Of course, there's nothing to stop you creating a helper function:

```
function addLIwithText(ul,text) {
    ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
                       .appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
}
```

Then your loop contents become:

```
addLIwithText(list,"ShopName : "+item.retailerName);
// and so on
```